# Search in a big dictionary Python

Tags: python, performance, search, hash-map, natural-language-processing

I have a big Python dictionary with more then 150,000 keys every key has list value. This dictionary contains infinitive words as key and all grammatical forms of these words as values:

```
 {"конфузити": ["конфузить", "конфужу", "конфузиш", "конфузить", "конфузим", "конфузимо", "конфузите", "конфузять", "конфузитиму", "конфузитимеш", "конфузитиме", "конфузитимем", "конфузитимемо", "конфузитимете", "конфузитимуть", "конфузив", "конфузила", "конфузило", "конфузили"]}
```

I formed list of words from particular text there are  more then 2m words in it, every word has it's grammatical form. So what I am trying to do is searching  these words in my dictionary values and returning dictionary keys, which as I have already told, are base or dictionary forms of words. This process is called [lemmatization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemmatisation). Have tried different approaches but they are all too slow.

In this part I perform text tokenization.

```
lst =[]
with open("/home/yan/PycharmProjects/vk/my_patrioty/men_patrioty.txt", 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    for sent in f:
        sent = sent.lower()
        sent = re.sub("[A-z0-9\'\"`\|\/\+\#\,\)\(\?\!\B\-\:\=\;\.\«\»\—\@]", '', sent)
        sent = re.findall('\w+', sent)
        for word in sent:
            lst.append(word)
```

In this part I am trying to perform binary search but is very slow.

```
with open("/home/yan/data.txt") as f:
    d = json.load(f)
    for w in lst:   #list of my words
        for key, value in d.items():
            lb = 0
            ub = len(value)
            mid_index = (lb + ub) // 2
            item_at_mid = value[mid_index]
            if item_at_mid == w:
                    print(key)
            if item_at_mid < w:
                    lb = mid_index + 1
            else:
                ub = mid_index
```

This is liner search it is a bit faster. But still not enough fast for my amount of data.

```
with open("/home/yan/data.txt") as f:
    d = json.load(f)  #dictionary to search in
    for w in lst:
        for key, value in d.items():
              if w in value:
                  print(key)
```

Below you can find links to my dictionary and sample of data to test it. If somebody does not know it is Ukrainian language that is presented in data set.

Dictionary data:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByIY5scTeLYqbXp6OExKa0xXbDg/view?usp=sharing

Sample of text:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByIY5scTeLYqMHhHbUJ5aXRWdWs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: So, given a particular form of a word, you want to efficiently come up with the infinitive version?

Comment: Yes, I want to get infinitive of words in the text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest turning the problem around. A dictionary is really good for looking up the key, but not for finding a key for a specific value.

First, you need to convert your dictionary to a dictionary in reverse:

```
with open("/home/yan/data.txt") as f:
    kv_dict = json.load(f)

vk_dict = {}
for k, vs in kv_dict.items():
    for v in vs:
        vk_dict.setdefault(v, []).append(k)

with open("/home/yan/data_rev.txt", "w") as f:
    json.dump(vk_dict, f)
```

Then, in your code, you can just write

```
with open("/home/yan/data_rev.txt") as f:
    d = json.load(f)

for w in list:
    for k in d.get(w, [])
        print(k)
```

The advantage: building data_rev.txt only needs to be done when data.txt changes, which is hopefully not that often.

Comment: Isn't `v` a list? so you'd need something like `{k: i for k, v in kv_dict for i in v}`?

Comment: Yes. Bit of a typo. Also need to add something to handle value-clashes. I'll edit later.

Comment: gives error TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: Made an edit. Idea was to use each seperate word as key mapping back to its stem, it should work now.

Comment: Yes, I made it before  thanks, just wanted to show how to improve your answer.

Comment: and with your new code it adds only one value to keys not all.

Comment: with open("/home/yan/data.txt") as f:
    kv_dict = json.load(f)

vk_dict = {}
for k, vs in kv_dict.items():
    vs = str(vs)
    vs  = re.sub("[\[\]]", '', vs)
    vk_dict[vs] = k



with open("/home/yan/data_rev.txt", "w") as f:
    json.dump(vk_dict, f, ensure_ascii=False)

Comment: I was trying your approach, but it seems does not work correctly. Maybe i missing something?

Comment: @Yan Which part doesn't work? In the second code block they didn't test if the word is in the list, to fix this you can use: `for word in (d[w] for w in lst if w in d): print word`, or another more readable way.

Comment: it does not work correctly.

Comment: I made some changes which might help, or might not. Anyway, if this doesn't work, I'm a bit at a loss as to how to continue further. But I'm glad that vnp's answer helped you improve the performance already.

Comment: no unfortunately it does not work((((

Comment: @Yan so, you're telling me that [this](http://pastebin.com/LZKBV6XJ) doesn't work?

Comment: no it works but not correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Do not iterate over the whole dictionary, most of the entries shouldn't be considered at all. You need a preliminary stage to select viable candidates.

One possible approach is to have a sorted list of base forms. Now given a word, find its lower and upper bounds, and inspect only base forms in this range.

From a cursory look at your dictionary, I would suggest to modify it slightly. Move the base form into the paradigm, and let key be a longest common prefix. Limit the search range same way as above.

It may (and will) fail in some corner cases. Alternation, reduction, etc, must be addressed separately.

Edit:

The modified dictionary would look like

```
{"конфу": ["зити", "зить", "жу", "зиш", "зить", "зим", "зимо", "зите", "зять", "зитиму", "зитимеш", "зитиме", "зитимем", "зитимемо", "зитимете", "зитимуть", "зив", "зила", "зило", "зили"]}
```

The key could be made a bit longer, but then you'd have to account for з-ж alternation; would it be beneficial or detrimental depends on access pattern.

Comment: Your approach is very good I just use set() on my word list and now I have 242,954 words before had 2,299,535. Now it will be way faster.

Comment: Move the base form into the paradigm, and let key be a longest common prefix. Did not get what do you mean by this? Can you provide an example?

Comment: @Yan See the edit

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution to my issue, maybe not the best but it works much faster than my previous approaches. Basically I modified my dictionary, example of it you can see in my question. Now it is [json lines file](http://jsonlines.org/)
And when I perform liner search on it and works much faster because it returns not word by word as it was before but all words in the same time. For example if there are 10 words **working** in my list it will lematize 10 of them at the same time. In 40 min it has lematized 30,000 words.

Dump into json lines:

```
def dumping_into_json(input_file, output):
    with open(input_file, encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as f:
        for i in file:
            with open(output, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as file1:
                file1.write('%s\n' % json.dumps(i, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Liner search:

```
with open("/home/yan/lem") as lem:
    for i in lem:
        i = json.loads(i)
        for w in lst:
            for key, value in i.items():
                if w in value:
                    print(key)
```